# AWS CloudFront with S3 origin - CloudFront Function VIEWER_RESPONSE not invoked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a application behind CloudFront, where most paths are backed by an API (currently external) and all UI resources are in S3.

I want to respond with the `index.html` file for all 404s, but only for the S3 origin.

Previously, I configured a errorResponse for all 404s to respond with the `index.html` which works. But this also leads to all 404s of the API being updated to a 200 with the content of the `index.html` because the errorResponse configuration is for the whole Distribution (so far everything as expected).

Now, I created a CloudFront Function using the following code:

```js
function handler(event) {
  if (event.response.statusCode === 404) {
    event.response.statusCode = 501;
    event.response.statusDescription = 'Not Implemented';
  }

  return event.response;
}
```

And associated it with the default behavior (S3) in CDK:

```
            defaultBehavior: {
                origin: new S3Origin(Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'UIResourcesBucket', props.uiResourcesBucketName)),
                compress: true,
                viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
                allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_GET_HEAD,
                cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_OPTIMIZED,
                originRequestPolicy: OriginRequestPolicy.CORS_S3_ORIGIN,
                responseHeadersPolicy: uiResponseHeadersPolicy,
                functionAssociations: [
                    {
                        function: new Function(this, 'UIResources404Function', {
                            code: FunctionCode.fromFile({ filePath: 'resources/cloudfront_function_redirect_404.js' }),
                        }),
                        eventType: FunctionEventType.VIEWER_RESPONSE,
                    },
                ],
            },
```

And I have updated the errorResponse configuration to act on 501 instead of 404 (since I don't use any 501s in the API):

```
            errorResponses: [
                {
                    httpStatus: 501,
                    ttl: Duration.seconds(30),
                    responseHttpStatus: 200,
                    responsePagePath: '/index.html',
                }
            ],
```

I can verify all the changes are deployed as expected.

Requesting any object that is *not* matched by the default behavior (meaning any API request) now successfully returns 404 where it should.

However, even for the default behavior (S3) requests where there's no object in S3 I see 404 responses.

I'm not sure if it would even work with a VIEWER_RESPONSE Function and then following the configured errorResponse (404 -> 501 -> 200), BUT I expected to see at least an 501 now for objects that don't exist in S3.

What I get back from CloudFront when performing a request against something that ends up with the default behavior (S3) but doesn't exist in S3:

```xml
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>aadsiaodhai</Key>
<RequestId>removed</RequestId>
<HostId>removed</HostId>
</Error>
```

The requests I tried were *not* cached by CloudFront (I can see `x-cache: Error from cloudfront` in the response). I also performed an invalidation on `/*` before testing my changes.

When using the "Test" functionality in the AWS Console for CloudFront Functions using somepath and 404 response code, the output is as expected a `501`. I can also confirm the function is deployed to Live.

In the monitoring tab I can't see a single invocation of this CloudFront Function.

All of this leads me to the conclusion that the CloudFront Function was never invoked.

Are there any restrictions with CloudFront Functions when using S3 origins? Is there anything else I could do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: For better separation, you can create 2 Cloud Front distribution as well. That would be neat and clean solution.

Comment: @AnkushJain I thought about this before, but this would also come with double the cost and some added latency which I'd like to avoid both

Comment: I found the answer to why the function is not invoked here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html "CloudFront does not invoke edge functions for viewer response events when the origin returns HTTP status code 400 or higher."

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html), CloudFront Functions for Viewer Response are not supported for response codes >=400. That explains why my Function was never invoked.

I managed to solve my issue by using a Viewer Request Function.

### Updated Answer:

Since I know all paths for my UI (SPA) never contain any filename extension (i.e. `.js`, `.txt`) and all requests coming to the S3 origin for objects that contain one should actually be resolved by S3 directly, I now use a Viewer Request function which returns the original request for known suffixes and modifies the request uri for all which don't have a known suffix:

```js
function buildCloudFront404RedirectFunction(defaultRootObject: string): string {
    // json is valid js syntax, so we can just put it directly into the js code
    const ignoreSuffixesJSON = JSON.stringify({
        '.png': true,
        '.zip': true,
        '.svg': true,
        '.txt': true,
        '.html': true,
        '.js': true,
        '.css': true,
        '.ico': true,
    });
    const defaultRootObjectJSON = JSON.stringify(`/${defaultRootObject}`);

    return `
var IGNORE_SUFFIXES = ${ignoreSuffixesJSON};
function handler(event) {
  var suffixIndex = event.request.uri.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (suffixIndex !== -1) {
    var suffix = event.request.uri.substring(suffixIndex);
    if (IGNORE_SUFFIXES[suffix]) {
      return event.request;
    }
  }

  event.request.uri = ${defaultRootObjectJSON};
  return event.request;
}
    `;
}
```

### Original Answer:

I now use this code to dynamically create a CloudFront function for Viewer Request:

```js
function buildCloudFront404RedirectFunction(knownFilesNames: ReadonlyArray<string>, defaultRootObject: string): string {
    // json is valid js syntax, so we can just put it directly into the js code
    const fileNamesJSON = JSON.stringify(knownFilesNames);
    const defaultRootObjectJSON = JSON.stringify(defaultRootObject);

    return `
var KNOWN_FILE_NAMES = ${fileNamesJSON};
function handler(event) {
  var isRequestForKnownFileName = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < KNOWN_FILE_NAMES.length; i++) {
    if (event.request.uri.endsWith(KNOWN_FILE_NAMES[i])) {
      isRequestForKnownFileName = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!isRequestForKnownFileName) {
    event.request.uri = ${defaultRootObjectJSON};        
  }

  return event.request;
}
    `;
}
```

And I use this helper to extract the filenames of my UI resources zip file:

```js
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';

export async function getFileNamesFromZip(zipFilePath: string): Promise<ReadonlyArray<string>> {
  const buf = await fs.readFile(zipFilePath);
  const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(buf);
  const fileNames = [];

  for (const [fileName, obj] of Object.entries(zip.files)) {
    if (!obj.dir) {
      fileNames.push(fileName);
    }
  }

  return fileNames;
}
```

Note that this only works if you know all your filenames during CDK synth AND the code is not perfect: since it's based on `uri.endsWith` it will match if `/something/index.html` is requested even if your files only contain a `/index.html` but not a `/something/index.html`.